# How can the ogr2ogr help to merge a shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, merge

I have over 30 shp files which is named "street.shp" into the sub-folder. There is over 30 sub-folders. In the sub-folder, there is another shp files which may be named a building.shp...etc. I only want to merge the street.shp files. The structure of all street.shp is exactly same!

I tried this script -

```
for /R %f in (*.shp) do ogr2ogr -update -append merge.shp %f -f “esri shapefile” -nln merge
```

How can the script find the shp file named "street.shp" only? Thanks a lot.

Comment: How can you have 30 shapefiles with the same name in a subfolder? Do you mean you have a lot of separate subfolders each of which may contain a street.shp? Perhaps you can edit the question to clarify the actual structure? Does for /R %f in (*\street.shp)... work in windows?

Comment: Thanks BradHards, for /R %f in (*\street.shp) do ogr2ogr -update -append merge.shp %f -f “esri shapefile” -nln merge is not work!

Comment: You still haven't answered my question about the actual data structure. You also haven't told me what happens (other than the not-very-informative "not work"). Please edit your question.

Comment: Updated! I tried "for /R %f in (*\street.shp) do ogr2ogr -update -append merge.shp %f -f “esri shapefile” -nln merge" (((No error message! The merge.shp is keep same!)))

Comment: OK, how about for /R %f in (*) do if exist(%f\street.shp) ogr2ogr -update -append merge.shp %f\street.shp -f “esri shapefile” -nln merge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do it with:

```
for /R %f in (*street.shp) do ogr2ogr -update -append merge.shp %f -nln merge
```

Note: `-f “esri shapefile”` is useless here, because is default output format for `ogr2ogr`. So it can be avoided.